# How to query list elements using spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

**Context:**
Salad contains multiple vegetables. Lets assume that recipe of the salad is to add vegetables in the given order so the order also needs to be persisted

Here are the class definitions

```
public class Salad {
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private List<Vegetable> veggies = new ArrayList<Vegetable>();
  //setters and getters
}

public class Vegetable {
 private String name;
 private String description;
 //setters and getters
}
```

Here is the hibernate-mapping.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Salad" table="SALAD">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="sequence"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="description"/>
        <list name=veggies cascade="all-delete-orphan" table="SALAD_VEGGIES" lazy="false">
          <key column="salad_id" />
          <list-index column="idx" />
          <many-to-many column="veg_id" class="Vegetable" />
        </list>
    </class>
    <class name="Vegetable" table="VEGETABLE">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="sequence"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="description"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

1. I am using the List because sequence of the vegetables have to preserved
2. When saving the salad, constituent vegetables already exists in the Vegetables table

**Objective:**
Create a JPQ query to fetch the list of all the vegetables involved for a given salad

What I tried?
1)

```
SELECT v FROM SALAD.veggies v where v.salad_id = :salad_id
```

which didn't work. How to query on a table that doesn't have a class (like List and Map? variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT v FROM Salad s JOIN s.veggies v where s.id = :salad_id
```

Remember: in JPQL you work with Java fields, not with column names. Also there is not relationship from `Vegetable` entity to the `Salad` entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can even say

```
select v from Vegetable v where v.salad_id = :saladId
```

Comment: Vegetable doesn't have salad mapping

Comment: who is the parent of the relationship? looks like a one to many relationship(salad - veggie) then how does the veggie not have the id of the salad in it, looks fishy